# How to share code documentation for a project?

Tags: c#, java, .net, tfs

There was a similar-ish question here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475795/how-do-you-share-code-across-teams-working-on-very-different-projects but mine is about writing documentation.

**Scenario:**

Let's say my team is working on a software project, a Fany-WordPad like application which has a feature called **Fancy-Word-Art** ( just like MS Office's word Art). Now I wrote the code for the main window( using WPF in .Net, or using Window Builder in Java, doesn't matter which tool/language).

Now if my colleague Mr Spongebob is writing the Word-Art part, how would I **tell him** what functions to call / Api to use to draw on my window? i.e. How do I let Mr SpongeBob know that he needs to call GetWindow() method to get a reference to the drawing surface, the parameters he needs to pass along , and so on?

I hope I am being clear here. Is this the procedure?

**Step 1 :** Use your company wiki site to understand your colleague's written code

**Step 2 :** Write the `GetWindow()` method so that it works well with the rest of the project

**Step 2 :** Now put a wiki on your intranet with the method parameters/ data type requirement  for your `GetWindow()` method  or use Doxygen/ Confluence  as suggested below

**Step 3 :** Now its your colleague Mr Spongebob's headache how to find how to draw his word-art on my window.

This just doesnt sound right .. With tons of functions, Spongebob's life will be hard, just as mine. Both of us rummaging through documentation to find the right functions to do our job. What if then I change `GetWindow() to GetWindow(string title)`.. Now how do I `literally tell` the poor spongebob he needs to redo his code.

Am I missing something here? Please share your experience, how do you tackle this problem in a real world software house environment? If your fellow developer is on the next table , do you actually **show** them how to implement a certain method as they get stuck, or how do you deal with this situation?
thank you

Thanks

Comment: This question is suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you need both API documentation and plenty of examples.

You might get some mileage out of documenting your code of course, but if you're truly writing a system properly, your clients will never see your code.  (That goes for clients in the calling sense, not necessarily in the "paying for your services" sense).

That's a fundamental of good practice and SOA, so you should really discard the "self documenting code" approach.

An alphabetic list of functions/methods/properties/whatever has value once the client has "got it" but until then, it's not immediately useful.

So that leaves you with having to showcase your creation.  Give a bunch of immediately useful examples that demonstrate the kind of thing you envisaged.  Make sure you have a simple example that demonstrates every function in its basic form with minimal interaction with the rest of the system (too many required interactions and you've probably not got a clean system anyway).

Once you have that, put it on a Wiki and encourage your users to enhance it.  Consider using something interactive like a Stack-Overflow-like platform.  MSDN is a good model but their examples often suck and can lack context.  You might have the luxury of having more tight and specific uses than, say, the entire .NET framework.  Early response to questions and updates to your examples/documentation will ensure your message gets across in the vital early days.  This will help your documentation burden tail off quickly by looking after your clients and giving them useful, practical help.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So....I have to first spend time writing the GetWindow() method , then I have to write a wiki ...... ? I'll probably have tons of functions...thats TONS of documentation... Is that how usually things are done? I mean, it will be easier ifI could just "tell" him which function to use, like actually telling him ....

Comment: I mean, is this how you guys do development at your workplace, if you do thats great because then I know that this system works for you? :)

Comment: It depends on whether you want to spend your time writing documentation & wikis once or sitting down with everyone who is going to use your API.  Actually it's down to what your employer wants so you should probably take it up with your boss.  Alternatively, talk to everyone that is going to use it and ask them.  Personally I think it's quite easy to do - it's just another step in the SDLC - you refactor the documentation as you add/remove/twiddle with the functionality.  Compared to thinking about and writing the code it's nothing.  It also makes you stop & think about your API/model.

Comment: +1 for "take it up with your boss".... except that at present I am the boss myself :(

Comment: Here's an example of a product with a complex API that I use.  It's not the best example in some ways but it really gets to the nuts and bolts of capability and how to achieve certain things.  If you get the product you get some actual project code to show it off too.  In your case, you could give away your Unit Test projects I guess.  


http://www.smartxls.com/sample-list.htm and 


http://www.smartxls.com/sample-list.htm

Comment: There are some really good answers here, It was hard to pick one...I accepted yours as I was looking for someone to explain what the actually do at their workplace. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A good question. Of course i do not have the universal solution. Code documentation in msdn/sun style is a good base. But for concepts, architecture and so one you need more than this. In some projects we use wikis for that. For customer requests, we have a kind of ticket-system where we also store some (no-code) information to solution. All in all there is no central place for all the documentaion stuff.

Edit: Your code in self is often the best documentation, following clean code guidelines or something else is a real best practice :-)

Comment: So there is no universal consensus on this? But this is , atleast in my opinion, hugely important and affects every single medium to large sized project....

Comment: I no what you mean. But how will there be a universal consensus? You sad the right keyword: 'project' - you have every time a other situation in how many people are involved, distributed teams, different customers, organization rules, ... So how can there be a universal consensus? Maybe best practices for certain general conditions.

Comment: You're right... I think universal consensus would be the wrong word. Now one COULD use TFS or SVN and share these documentation files sure, but I just thought that everyone here has worked on many projects. SUrely there is a method that most people use which I should give a go rather than inventing my own. :)

Comment: Sorry Micha , your answer is good, but I have unaccepted it temporarily, to encourage some more discussion and a detailed answer here..... if I don't get anything then the bounty is all yours :D

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it  Was a interesting trick to get more attention for your question

Answer (score 4):

Wikis are a cracking idea (good suggestion @Micha!). I used to use one in a previous company for a large engineering software/hardware project.  It obviously spanned hardware and software  guys and so it was a great way to share info across all teams.  It's really useful if it's a long term project too - you can keep track of changes to functionality/API as things inevitably morph over time.

We used a paid service - [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/overview/team-collaboration-software) if I remember rightly; but there are free wiki hosting sites too e.g. [wikihost](http://www.wikihost.org/) (just a quick google search, I can't vouch for them).

On another note though - have you thought about self documenting code at all?  For example "Doxygen" or similar?  Takes a lot of pain out of documenting every single function and also sets up a decent framework that can be padded out with more info where necessary.  It also creates a nice UI for stepping through all the functions /class etc.

**Edit:** I've actually just started using Google Sites (sites.google.com) to create a wiki for a dev team I'm not working with.  It's free (as in 'beer') and seems pretty good so far, although it does lack auto code formatting.

Comment: Well, I have thought, (and used ) self documenting but rather than reinventing the wheel, I figure that all the experienced people we have here, they must have a system in place already.

Comment: I can recommand Doxygen. Really simple of a casual programmer. Been working with javadoc and Doxygen was really the best to use. Of course, you have Sandcastle and so on, but Doxygen was easier for me to use. A small XML comment in your code helps often the other developers who aren't familiar with the software to understand methods pretty fast.

Comment: Doxygen? I 'll check that.. the google site wiki sounds good as well, better actually...

Comment: although I accepted a different answer below, I personally found this answer useful, hence the bounty awarded :D

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I use a short description in my class files at the top, like:

```
//======
//
//  modul:      fileRunner.cs
//  ...
//  what:       for playing audio/video
//  depends on: consoleOutput.cs (Form)
//
//=======
#region HowToUse
//=======
//
//          HowToUse
//
//      1. create instance of fileRunner:
//          fileRunner p = new fileRunner();
//      2. run console program [progPath] with arguments [cmdsString]
//          string output = p.RunExternalExe(progPath, cmdsString);
//      3. handle [output]
//          if (output == "anyError"){do something;}
//
//  [OUTPUT]
//      "0" : process ended w/o errors
//      "C" : canceled by user
//      else: output is the string of the StdError, the called program submitted + StdOut after "Std output:"
//
//  IMPORTANT
//  Mention, this file depends on consoleOutput.cs to parse the output for gui.
//  It doesn't support input ways, because the way ffmpeg is outputting doesn't allow it, it's not active
//=======
#endregion
```

For other classes I just named the public functions, that are self-describing.
An other option is to write on the top that they should look an the comment in the code and on the top of the public functions I use similar explanations:

```
#region convert an audio or video file from a drop
// FUNCTION:    convertTo
// DOES:        converting a file from a drop
//              does not delete the original
// INPUT1:      [path] as string, 
//                  path to the destination file
// INPUT2:      [e] as System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs,
//                  the args, the drop-object submits
//                  path of source file is in here
// OUTPUT:      isConverted as bool,
//                  true if not (canceled or error raised)
    public bool convertTo(string pWorkingFile, DragEventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    }
#endregion
```

If something changes you can mention it at the top too.
I think with SCM software it's a good option to mention the most important w/o wasting too much time on documentation.

Comment: just a bit of elaboration:  how do you "tell" them that there is a fileRunner.cs file to be instantiated/used? ( I mean actually telling them literally) You could have called it fileJogger.cs too... how do you convey that? Or do you compile it as a library and tell them to reference the library?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question well... in my published projects, each file has such a header with the "depends on:", where all needed are mentioned. So anybody can look at them, if needed. They also have the option to jump to the definition with F12 wich is more easier. And for new files I mention it in the SCM app that there is a new file with new functions. I think in C# it's not so important, because it's more a `namespace` issue than an `inlucde` one. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @gu471 Might I ask why you use a regular Comment (`//`) instead of a XML-Comment (`///`) which is meant specifically for the purpose of documentation? [Article on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx)

Comment: Great, thanks for the hint! I didn't searched for something like that, therefore I simply used comments ;)

Comment: Awesome documentation... if only everyone would do this to their code!!! (when appropriate of course)

Answer (score 0):

as Stupid as it sounds, I would write him (Spongebob) a mail, or just tell him what he will need. If you already know who will need something in the near future, it is great if you can inform those peope before they strat to search and get headaches. Not everything in a project needs a technical Solution very often a human to human is much better.

Your documentation can also be in a wiki and then you can simply send Spongebob a link.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the pain involved in changing specifications over a large api, I'd suggest you follow the msdn/javadoc convention as mentioned earlier and also advice your team mate to use a modern IDE with autocompletion/autosuggest feature. Most of the common editors that provide auto suggestion also display documentation for the method/member to be used.
If you are seeking agile here, then docs and wikis are slight overkill; my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put your work in one git/svn project instead of working on the project parts independently? Then when you change a core function, you will see what it breaks and be responsible for fixing the methods that call it before committing your changes.

I am not a big fan of documenting extensively during development. It slows you down too much and you will have to redo it over and over again. Just create descriptive method names and be generous with you in-code comments.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

To help the situation between spongebob and yourself working together you will need some sort of Code Asset Management software (GIT, TFS, etc).

*What if then I change GetWindow() to GetWindow(string title).. Now how do I literally tell the poor spongebob he needs to redo his code.*

You should always start your day coding by "GET LATEST", meaning download code from the repository. If spongebob does this he will immediately see that he now needs to pass in string title as his code will stop compiling. It would be preferable that you literally tell spongebob that you have changed your code and he now needs to pass in a value, but if you are both checking in code every night and getting latest when you start coding for the day you should be both informed.

As far as the use of a WIKI or if you use Sharepoint doesnt matter. I would say to make it a little more efficient why not do this:

In your document repository (Wiki/Sharepoint) call the files by the page name so one is WordArt, the other is MainDocument, maybe one is PrintDocument (assuming these are different pages) and in the code you can simply put:

For more information on this visit the *_*__site at :http://yourrespositoryname.com/nameofprocedure

Comment: As much as you are not a fan of the "Wiki's" its imporant not just for you and spongebob. What if Donald Duck joins the team and now he needs to understand whats going on. He is now tasked with writing an addition that makes the Word ART 3-D if the user so chooses. He could easily go to the wiki and see the WordArt documentation and know that he could right the 3D version using that one as a guide.

Comment: I had to choose a cartoon character able to handle water. Perhaps nemo would have been a better choice!  Some great answers in this thread!